# Why Raikage didn't consider Minato using Body Flicker in their fight?

Tags: naruto

In his fight against Raikage, Minato spread his marked Kunai to many locations.
It seemed like the Raikage was very sure that Minato would only appear at the marked area/kunai.

My question is, can Minato appear at unmarked location using Body Flicker? I think he obviously can. If so, then why Raikage didn't consider this in their fight?

Answer (score 2):

Minato's [Flying Thunder God Techniqie](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_Technique) allows him to teleport to any location which he has previously marked with a hand seal (either on a kunai or with his hand). The jutsu, which was Originally created by the The 2nd Hokage (Tobirama Senju) was perfected by Minato to the point where the "hand-marked" seal never disappeared from whoever Minato marked.

> Both Tobirama and Minato were famed as the fastest shinobi during their lifetimes. While both were very fast on their own, the Flying Thunder God also contributed to their fame.

The reason why Raikage A did not anticipate Minato's offense was because he did not know enough about Minato's Flying Raijin Jutsu. The rumors about Minato would have spread tales about how he could teleport to whatever Kunai he threw around but apparently Minato also had "some extra's up his sleeve" which only a few people knew about.

Minato was actually very fast in normal speed. To be able to react to Raikage A's top speed on lightning chakra mode and even counter attack.

> Before the Flying Thunder God Technique can be performed, users must first mark a target with their "technique formula"

Minato did not "just magically appear" at the back of Killer bee during [Their Fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWqweyUXIrQ), what actually happened was that Minato used his hand to mark Bee a split second after dodging and cutting his tail. Raikage was trying to figure out which of the kunais that Minato would flicker to, little did he know Minato had already teleported to the mark he placed on Bee.

Comment: Oh, I think you misunderstood my question. I know that Minato had marked Bee, and he used that mark to teleported to Bee. My question is, why Raikage only anticipate Minato to appear at his Kunai, not to any other places using Body Flicker, just like what other shinobi could do? I'm not native speaker so my wording might be confusing.

Comment: ooh, alright now I get what you mean @Albert.  Its because of the rumors he's heard of about Minato using lots of kunais to easily move around. Since Minato spread his Kunais around, raikage was expecting him  to dodge easily with his famed "Flying Raijin" technique. Also, Raikage was at his top speed when he went after Minato, and he probably thought that the only way Minato could dodge his fastest mode attack was if he teleported away to the Kunais.

Answer (score 0):

Minato is fast. His teleportation is instant and his reaction time and speed is enough to be able to teleport to dodge almost anything. But there in lies his flaw, its his reaction speed that is his own. His physical speed is great, but it is not the reason why he is truly fast.

The Raikage on the other hand is all physical speed and he has mastered Body Flicker. He uses his Lighting style to enhance it to incredible proportions, resulting in him being one of the fastest Shinobi. He is one of the few people specifically mentioned on the [Body Flicker Wiki page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Body_Flicker_Technique) for his increadible skill with it.

It is those 2 different techniques that explain why Minato did not use Body Flicker. Minato is physically slower than the Raikage. He has top tier reaction speed, and his teleportation is instant, but his running speed is not. To use Body Flicker against the Raikage would be like an average runner trying to outrun an Olympic Sprinter. He would most likely loose every time and get caught, resulting in him teleporting anyway for a waste of stamina and chakra. The Raikage knew this.

TL;DR Minato using Body Flicker would always loose to the Raikage and his top tier mastery of Body Flicker that has been enhanced by lighting style to be even faster. Minato could only outrun him by using teleportation. Any attempt to use Body Flicker would result in him loosing the footrace.

Comment: (reply to deleted comment) It indeed is not clear, but if Minato's body flicker were comparable to A's, then Teleportation would have been a huge waste of chakra. No way Flying Raijin is not many times more expensive than a short body flicker. Minato threw dozens of Kunai and left them there when he retreated, realistically almost all the ones he had without summoning more. Its like Sasuke using 1 of his 2 chidori attacks per day during the chunin exams, extremely expensive, and a very bad idea in the middle of a warzone, unless you absolutely had to in order to ensure victory.

Answer (score 0):

Minato's body flicker is on par with A's. Minato during the war was able to place markers in 5 locations b4 the other kage even got there. 4 for the barrier without being noticed. It's a translation problem. When sasuke used body flicker to blitz naruto and to blitz tobi and deidara tobi called it teleportation. Minato was using body flicker to set those markers. Cleary tobirama and minato and the other kage didnt teleport to the battlefield bcuz they had no marker to do so. It's not that minato couldnt use the body flicker to appear some where else in the field against A. I think it's just strategy. All the kunai makes it hard to predict his next move. And since there speed Is comparable A could probably follow. I dont think minato is slower in raw speed. The ftg is faster and leaves no trace. His reaction speed, body flicker, and ftg all contributed to his nickname. He has reaction speed and ftg over A. He surpasses the 2nd in all three. Altoutgh the 2nd only has ftg over A.

Answer (score -1):

Minato cannot teleport to locations where he hasn't marked before. Flying Raijin 2 developed by Minato enables him to teleport to locations which are previously marked, but he doesn't need a Kunai to do so.

Comment: Can he appear to unmarked location using Body Flicker? And if so why Raikage didn't anticipate that as well? This is my question.